# Authorize function is not working with middleware | Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, rest

I have an authorization using middleware where Function could only run when authorized

this is my middleware:

```
class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->is_admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return abort(403, 'Forbidden');
    }
}
```

my Controller:

```
public function destroy(int $bookId, int $reviewId, Request $request)
{
    // @TODO implement

    $check_bookReview = BookReview::firstWhere('id', $reviewId)->where('book_id', $bookId);
    if ($check_bookReview && isAdmin()) {
        BookReview::destroy($reviewId);
        return response()->noContent();
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

and my `api.php` as well my `Kernel`:

```
'auth.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.admin']], function (){
Route::post('/books', 'BooksController@store');
Route::post('/books/{id}/reviews', 'BooksReviewController@store');
Route::delete('/books/{bookId}/reviews/{reviewId}', 'BooksReviewController@destroy');
});
```

and i have a `User` db field where it contains `api_token` and `is_admin` like below:
[image: User DB]

and my Postman still return 403 forbidden while i already gave an authorization by headers:
[image: Postman]

what should i do here, to fulfill my function?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `Authenticate` middleware is not working, so it likely fails on `auth()->check()`.

Make sure to use the `auth` middleware from Laravel, you can also use a guard as described here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: i've changed it into auth middleware from laravel, its still the same, what i don't understand is am i doing the correct way on my postman?

Comment: Still the same meaning what error exactly? (You have suspicious `isAdmin()` function call in the controller which shouldn’t be there..

Comment: isAdmin() is my middleware class for authorization in my route, the error is forbidden 403 in postman which when I implement middleware auth in my route

Comment: Show the error. Also I mean the IsAdmin() function call you have **in the controller** which shouldn’t be there.

Comment: the error is in the picture above, the postman one.

i put it on the controller to check if user isAdmin() then function can run else 404

Comment: You need to use laravel’s `auth` middleware for `auth()->check()` to work first. Debug by checking your conditions separately to make sure which one is failing